# Change ListView Item Binding dynamically

Tags: c#, listview, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am making Windows 8.1 for app store with Visual Studio 2015. I have ListView with GridView which is working good. In some column there is TextBlock and its Text is Bind but I wanted to change the binding with different field on Radio Button Checked. Below is my code.

```
<ListView Name="lvData" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" 
                                    BorderThickness="1" Foreground="#000" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="Number" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="1" x:Uid="_Dept" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="2" x:Uid="Arr" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="3" x:Uid="CurrentStatus" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}" Content="{Binding Number}"/>
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="DepTime" Text="{Binding DeptTime}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Uid="Actual" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeptStn}" Foreground="SkyBlue" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </GridViewItem>
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArrTime" Text="{Binding ArrTime}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Uid="Actual" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArrivCode}" Foreground="SkyBlue" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </GridViewItem>
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}" Foreground="{Binding Color}" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentStatus}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </GridViewItem>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

In above code column index 1 and 2 have TextBlock text binding which I wanted to change on radio button checked event.

Comment: You can surely define binding programmatically, but maybe easier it would be if you have just defined two separate TextBlocks, each with different binding and just change their visibility depending on radio button - then almost everything can be defined in xaml.

Comment: That's good idea but thing is that, I cannot access the control inside the GridViewItem. Kindly can you help me on that

Comment: What do you mean by 'I cannot access the conrol inside GridViewItem'? Also - I can't see the radio button in your code.

Comment: You can see that controls (i.e. TextBlock) are under DataTemplete due to that I cannot see controls in code behind directly

Comment: Then there is more code in the behind. Can you share a minial sample project? You can also [look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838207(v=vs.95).aspx) if you really want to define binding in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was going on wrong direction, logic which @Romasz gave to keep visible on of was absolutely correct, but still I was going wrong path to access controls from code behind. But it cannot access from code behind as it is under DataTemplate.

So I created boolean **IValueConverter** as below

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then I added below in **Page.Resources**

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Then in actual TextBlock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DepTime" Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="65" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=LocalTime, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

In above ElementName=LocalTime because my radio button name is LocalTime

Hope it will help to somebody